LinkedIn API Error: connect ETIMEDOUT 108.174.10.22:443 or Other IP Address
I am encountering an issue with the LinkedIn API. When I try to retrieve posts using the following API endpoint:
https://api.linkedin.com/rest/posts?author={data}&q=author&count=20
I get the following error: Error: connect ETIMEDOUT 108.174.10.22:443
This issue is not limited to this API endpoint; I am experiencing the same error with other LinkedIn API endpoints and different IP addresses as well.
The APIs were working fine until the beginning of July, but they have stopped working now.
I have checked with multiple accounts and created multiple access tokens for LinkedIn, but it is still not working.
#linkedin
I have tried the following steps to resolve the issue:
Checked the LinkedIn API status page for any reported outages or issues.
Created multiple access tokens using different LinkedIn accounts to see if the issue was related to a specific account.
Tested different API endpoints to determine if the issue was isolated to a particular endpoint or affected all endpoints.
Despite these efforts, I am still encountering the ETIMEDOUT error. I expected the API to return the requested data as it did before the beginning of july. I am looking for assistance to identify and resolve the root cause of this issue.

This is probably more likely to be a connection issue from your end. Can you do a successful ping on the host name?

Yes, I tried it in the terminal, and its showing this .                                                   command :ping api.linkedin.com
PING api.linkedin.com (2620:109:c002::6cae:a16) 56 data bytes
64 bytes from 2620:109:c002::6cae:a16: icmp_seq=1 ttl=46 time=423 ms
64 bytes from 2620:109:c002::6cae:a16: icmp_seq=2 ttl=46 time=549 ms

It might be an issue with my code, but previously it was working smoothly. I have tested the APIs in Postman, but they're still not working.

The ping appears to be going towards an IPv6 address, whereas the error message you quoted contains an IPv4 address. So that is probably still indicative of some sort of DNS/routing problem.

Is there a way I can fix this issue on my side?

@CBroe   I’m getting a 500 Internal Server Error when testing this in Postman. Is there a way to fix this issue?

Sounds like you reached the endpoint then, but are sending wrong data. Does the response body not contain any more info about what went wrong?

@CBroe   To retrieve posts, I am using this endpoint: GET https://api.linkedin.com/rest/posts?q=author&count=10&sortBy=LAST_MODIFIED
Optional: author={organizationUri}
In some cases, we have an organization URI, and in others, we do not. Please check if we need to add anything extra.
